# Derive the execution time growth rate (BigO) of the following code

Tags: c++

What is execution time growth rate Big O of this code?

```
void doDiff(int setA[], int setB[], int sizeA, int sizeB)   {

   const int MAX = 10; 
   // validate setA and setB 
   if ((sizeA == 0) && (sizeB == 0))                    
         cout << "both sets are empty " << endl;    
   else
         cout << "symmetric difference: { " ;   

   for (int i = 0;  i <  sizeA;  i++ )            
       if (!member(setB, setA[i],sizeB))        
              cout << setA[i] << " ";           

   for (int i = 0;  i <  sizeB;i++ )            
       if (!member(setA, setB[i],sizeA))            
              cout << setB[i] << " ";                

   cout << "}" << endl;                 
}

bool member(int set[], int n, int size)
{
    for (; size > 0;  size--)               
        if (set[size-1] == n)                       
            return true;                    
  return false;         
}
```

When I calculate the big O of this code, I end up with `O(N*N*N) || O(N^3)`
I am not sure what exact execution time growth rate is for this code. 
please help me.

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: Please show your calculations leading to O(n^3).

Comment: that `else` doesn't look right.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Nice catch; there will be an extra } printed when both sets are empty, so its not VERY wrong :)

Comment: Top-down approach:
MAX[O(1),O(1)], O(1)], E=O (N) * MAX[O(1),O(1)], O(1)],  F= O(1),  G=O (N) * MAX[O(1),O(1)], O(1)], H=O(1)
= MAX[  A= O(1) ,   B= O(1) * O(1), C= O(1) * O(1), D= O (N) * O(1), O(1), E=O (N) *  O(1),  F= O(1),  G=O (N) *O(1), O(1), H=O(1)
= MAX[  A= O(1) , B=  O(1), C= O(1), D= O (N) , O(1), E=O (N) ,  F= O(1),  G=O (N) , O(1), H=O(1)
= MAX[   D= O (N), E=O (N) ,  G=O (N) 
= O(N*N*N) || O(N^3)

Comment: @user3447635: That's a lot of letters you've got there; except for N & O, there's no indication as to what any of them mean.

Comment: Actually, I used one method which labeling each bracket with an alphabet and then using a top-down approach to work out the big o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems inappropriate to fill an answer with questions, but since this sounds like homework, I think they're a better way to the goal (which is for YOU to figure out how this works):

1. What is the "big-O" of `member`?  This is important, since `doDiff` relies on it so much.
2. How many times does `doDiff` call `member`?
3. If every call to `member` takes the same amount of time, `member` is O(X), and `doDiff` calls `member` Y times, what is the "big-O" of `doDiff`?

Comment: Big O of member is O(N) because of the iteration of the for loop. doDiff calls the member method 2 times which become O(N^2). finally doDiff has two for loop which comes as O(N^2) as well. So the result comes as [O(N^2), O(N^2)] which equals = O(N^4) , i think

Comment: Calling O(N) twice isn't O(N^2); its O(2*N) which is the same as O(N).  Besides, member gets called a LOT more than twice.

Comment: Yeah, you right. that is awesome. I will try over again. Also could you please type the answer as that could very helpful. Thank you very much